# Identify Duplicates or COUNTIF > 255 characters (long text)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, countif

I have a strange problem, I have an excel document with two columns, col A contains the key, this is not unique, col b contains text of varying length, usually above 255 characters.

I'd like to apply a filter to column A to select two keys, this is fine, I'd then like to identity any duplicates that exists within column B - applying only to fields that are visible, i.e. as a result of the filter on column A.

This should be simple; however, the conditional formatting is failing to identify duplicates, I'm guessing because it does not like the length of the text.

Even trying this the mandrolic way fails as the search box appears to only be able to accept a search string of a certain length.

Comment: So if you have two string values in column B, each 550 characters in length and with identical 'keys' but one ends in a question mark and the other in an exclamation mark they are not duplicates. However if a third identical string with the same 'key' ends in a question mark then two rows are 'identified'. (still have no idea exactly what 'identified' is intended to mean)

Comment: Does it succeed with shorter strings then?

Comment: How many rows of data in column B? This may be a factor in deciding whether an array formula is appropriate?

Comment: not quite, the filter I apply in col A will show only values key1 and key3.  Its the resulting subset of data I need to highlight duplicates from.

Comment: About 500 rows in total

Comment: yes, apply condiitional formatting on other strings works fine.  It might be that these strings have been copied from a PDF, strange formatting perhaps ?  but then both strings would have been.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) has a string criteria limit of 255 characters.

> <sup>From [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)</sup>
> <sub>Wrong value returned for long strings.      *The COUNTIF function returns incorrect results when you use it to match strings longer than 255 characters.*</sub>

There is a work-around solution offered by support.office.com on the COUNTIF support page but I couldn't get it working so I wrote a User defined Function that does work and added hidden/visible and case sensitive options.

**[COUNTIFSBIGTXT function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688846/identify-duplicates-long-text/51689459#51689459)** - CountIfs functionality for criteria strings longer than 255 characters

Put this in a public module code sheet (alt+F11, Insert, Module).

```
Option Explicit

Function COUNTIFSBIGTXT(iOptions As Long, ParamArray pairs()) As Long
    'COUNTIFSBIGTXT - CountIfs functionality for criteria strings longer than 255 characters
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688846#51689459
    '
    ' =COUNTIFSBIGTXT(<options>, <string_range1>, <criteria1>, [string_range2], [criteria2], …)
    '        OPTIONS
    '      0 No options
    '     +1 Include hidden cells in <string_range1>, [string_range2], etc
    '     +2 Case sensitive comparison

    'throw error if string_range and criteria do not come in pairs
    If Not CBool(UBound(pairs) Mod 2) Then
        COUNTIFSBIGTXT = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'declare variables
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim bIncludeHidden As Boolean, bCaseSensitive As Boolean

    'set optional booleans
    bIncludeHidden = CBool(1 And iOptions)
    bCaseSensitive = CBool(2 And iOptions)

    'restrict full column references to the parent worksheet's UsedRange
    Set pairs(LBound(pairs)) = Intersect(pairs(LBound(pairs)), pairs(LBound(pairs)).Parent.UsedRange)

    'resize all <string_range> to the same dimensions
    With pairs(LBound(pairs))
        For i = LBound(pairs) + 2 To UBound(pairs) Step 2
            Set pairs(i) = pairs(i).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
            'Debug.Print pairs(i).Address(0, 0)
        Next i
    End With

    'loop cell count in pairs(LBound(pairs)) for relative ordinal
    For i = 1 To pairs(LBound(pairs)).Cells.Count
        'loop through each pair of <string_range> and <criteria>
        For j = LBound(pairs) To UBound(pairs) Step 2
            'exit for if any argument pair does not meet criteria
            With pairs(j).Cells(i)
                'throw out worksheet error codes
                If IsError(.Value) Then Exit For
                'do the pair(s) meet a case insensitive match
                If LCase(.Value2) <> LCase(pairs(j + 1)) Then Exit For
                'do the pair(s) meet a case sensitive match with option
                If .Value2 <> pairs(j + 1) And LCase(.Value2) = LCase(pairs(j + 1)) And bCaseSensitive Then Exit For
                'are the cells visible or hidden with include option
                If (.EntireRow.Hidden Or .EntireColumn.Hidden) And Not bIncludeHidden Then Exit For
            End With
        Next j

        'determine if all argument pairs matched
        If j > UBound(pairs) Then _
            COUNTIFSBIGTXT = COUNTIFSBIGTXT + 1
    Next i

End Function
```

**[Syntax:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688846#51689459)**

```
=COUNTIFSBIGTXT(<options>, <string_range1>, <criteria1>, [optional string_range2], [optional criteria2], …)
```

**[Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688846#51689459)**

[image]

**[Sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688846#51689459)**²

The following examples were based on 9 rows of an identical 600 character string with three rows forced to upper-case.

[image]

**[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719050#50719050)**

Simple COUNTIF operation discarding filtered/hidden rows and not case sensitive.

```
=COUNTIFSBIGTXT(0, B:B, B2)
```

[image]

**[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719050)**

Expanded COUNTIFS¹ operation discarding filtered/hidden rows but case sensitive string comparison. Secondary criteria with A:A equals the value in A2.

```
=COUNTIFSBIGTXT(2, B:B, B2, A:A, A2)
```

[image]

---

¹ <sub>The logic flow 'short-circuits' on fail. With multiple string/criteria pairs, you can enhance performance
    by listing the least likely string_range/criteria matches first. You might see similar increases in calculation
    efficiency for special circumstances by reordering the latter three 'kick-out' Exit For statements for your
    particular requirements but I recommend keeping the check for worksheet errors as the primary check.
    For example, if you have a lot of potential string matches but very few visible rows, moving the check
    for visible cells above the check for string matches would cut down on the criteria checks.</sub>

² <sub>Many thanks to the [Lorem Ipsum Generator](https://www.lipsum.com) for the sample string content.</sub>

Comment: Very nice. How does this bit work  please?   bIncludeHidden = CBool(1 And iOptions)   It is the presence of the 1 And that is confusing me.

Comment: @QHarr,  At least half the answer is in the documentation I provided. A VBA AND operator is Bitwise. Given 0, 1, 2, 4, 8 I can determine which of those are true if you supply a number between 0 and 15. Supply 9 and I can tell you that 1 and 8 are true, everything else is false. <more below>

Comment: @QHarr, Consider that False is zero and everything that is not False is true. That works in VBA until you introduce the AND operator because (1 And 3) is True but (1 And 4) is False. Initiate a chat for more info. (btw, that's why I wrap a lot of my criteria in CBool(...). I've been caught dodging the bitwise one too many times)

Comment: Superb answer - thank you for your efforts with this.  Worked well.

Comment: Well, oh-key-doh-key then.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to this late but posting this built in workaround to the countif limitation to 255 characters if it helps others.  You can use this substitution option that searches for a specific text string given in REF_TO_CELL_WITH_VALUE and searches the list referenced in REF_TO_YOUR_LIST.  It works by trying to replace instances of your text string in each item of the list and

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(REF_TO_YOUR_LIST)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(REF_TO_YOUR_LIST,REF_TO_CELL_WITH_VALUE,"")))/LEN(REF_TO_CELL_WITH_VALUE))
```