# Count unique values excel formula with Blanks - Countif shows a character limit error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to check if in a vertical array of 9 cells, whether any two or more (upto all 9 cells) comments are the same, rest may be blank. If they're the same, shows TRUE else FALSE.

The formula I was working with is given below and works perfectly. I used Sumproduct and CountIF together to solve this, but since CountIF has a 255 character limit, any comment above the **character limit** gives me a **#N/A** error.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($DU$3:$DU$11<>"")/COUNTIF($DU$3:$DU$11,$DU$3:$DU$11&""))=1
```

I am looking for the *CountIF* workaround in my listed formula which does  **not**  have a 255 character limit and can have larger text. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Got a formula that should do the trick:

```
=SUM(IF(DU3:DU11<>"",IF(DU3:DU11=TRANSPOSE(DU3:DU11),1,0),0))=COUNTA(DU3:DU11)
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

It will return `FALSE` if there are any duplicate values. It will return `TRUE` if no duplicates are used.

---

Another option would be to use a UDF, possibly the below:

```
Function UniqueVals(rng As Range) As Boolean

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim arr As Variant, x As Long
arr = rng.Value
For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(x, 1) <> "" Then
        If dict.Exists(arr(x, 1)) Then
            UniqueVals = False
            Exit For
        Else
            UniqueVals = True
            dict.Add arr(x, 1), 1
        End If
    End If
Next x

End Function
```

---

Call the above like `=UniqueVals(DU3:DU11)` and it will return `TRUE` if all values are unique. It will return `FALSE` if there are any duplicates.

---

Stumbled onto this [old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51688846/9758194) post on SO too.